# timeout in exec type container probe

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a question regarding the timeout in exec type container probe in openshift/kubernetes.
My openshift version is 3.11 which has kubernetes version 1.11

I have defined a readiness probe as stated below

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - check_readiness.sh
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 30
  failureThreshold: 1
```

according to openshift documentation timeoutSeconds parameter has no effect on the container probe for exec type probe.
check_readiness.sh script is a long running script and may take more than 5 mins to return.
After the container start i logged into the container to check the status of the script.
What i found is that after approx 2 min another check_readiness.sh script was started while the first one was still running and another one after approx 2 min.

Can someone explain what openshift or kubernetes doing with the probe in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct, Container Execution Checks do not support the `timeoutSeconds` argument. However, [as the documentation notes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/application_health.html), you can implement similar functionality with the `timeout` command:

```
[...]
      readinessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - '-c'
            - timeout 60 /opt/eap/bin/livenessProbe.sh 
        periodSeconds: 10
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 3
[...]
```

So in your case I am guessing the following is happening:

- Your container is started.
- After the duration `initialDelaySeconds` (30 seconds in your case), the first readiness probe is started and your script is executed.
- Then, after `periodSeconds` (30s) the next probe is launched, in your case leading to the script being executed the second time.
- Every 30s, the script is started again, even though the previous iteration(s) are still running.

So in your case you should either use the `timeout` command as seen in the documentation or increase the `periodSeconds` to make sure the two scripts are not executed simultaneously.

In general, I would recommend that you make sure your readiness-check-script returns much faster than multiple minutes to avoid these kind of problems.

Comment: I did some more test and it seems kubernetes allow a container exec type readiness probe to run for a maximum of 120s + timeout value. after that it spin another exec type probe while first one is still running. Is it possible to increase the 120s value ?